# RDD map each substring to another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapping, aggregate, rdd

I am not very familiar with functional programming. What I want to do is to take an RDD of strings, split them and then map each word as an entry to another RDD. My RDD contains strings which are tab separated.

I take the substring which I want to split and I map it as a whole string into another RDD. Then I collect the strings to main node and finally I split each word I want to map to another RDD. As a brute force approach I have done this:

```
var e1String = ""

val e1HashTagTemp = entitySetE1.map{ x=>
      var containedEntities = ""
      val entityString = x.split("\t")(2).split(" ")
      entityString.foreach(word => containedEntities += word.toLowerCase + " ")
      containedEntities
    } 

e1HashTagTemp.collect().foreach(x=> e1String += x)
val e1HashTags = sc.parallelize(e1String.split(" ")).distinct
```

I am pretty sure this is not the optimal solution for this scenario.

**example**:

> [RDD] entitySetE1 = ["test0 \t test1 \t this is the field i want to map  \t test3 \t
> test4", "test0 \t test1 \t map this again  \t test3 \t test4"]
>
> [RDD] e1HashTagTemp = ["this is the field i want to map", "map this again" ]
>
> [String] e1String = "this is the field i want to map map this again "
>
> [RDD] e1HashTags = ["this", "is". "the", "field", "i", "want", "to", "map", "again"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following will (almost) get what you want...

```
val e1HashTagTemp: RDD[String] = entitySetE1.flatMap(s => s.split("\t")).flatMap(t => t.split(" ")).map(u => u.toLowerCase)
```

...you could add a `.filterNot(word => word.contains("test"))` if you really need to filter out those words.

Comment: i modified it a little bit in order to split with my criteria :
entitySetE1.map(s => s.split("\t")(2))...
Nice idea, thanks.